# How to read buffered lines directly from curl in Rust

Tags: rust, libcurl

I'm using the `curl` crate to download a gzipped file:

```
use curl::easy::Easy;

fn download_file() -> MyResult<()> {
    let mut file = File::create("file.txt.gz")?;
    let mut easy = Easy::new();
    easy.url("https://example.com/file.txt.gz")?;
    easy.write_function(move |data| {
        file.write_all(data).unwrap();
        return Ok(data.len());
    })?;
    easy.perform()?;
    return Ok(());
}
```

I'm using the `flate2` crate to decompress the file, and read one line at a time:

```
use flate2::read::GzDecoder;

fn import_file() -> MyResult<()> {
    let file = File::open("file.txt.gz")?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(GzDecoder::new(file));
    for line in reader.lines() {
        let line = line?;
        println!("{line}");
    }
    return Ok(());
}
```

I would like to combine these steps, but `GzDecoder` requires an object implementing the `Read` trait, and I'm not sure how to hook that up to `Easy`.  I suspect this will require doing the download and import steps on separate threads:

```
use curl::easy::Easy;
use flate2::read::GzDecoder;

fn download_and_import_file() -> MyResult<()> {
    let handle = thread::spawn(|| {
        let mut easy = Easy::new();
        easy.url("https://example.com/file.txt.gz").unwrap();
        easy.write_function(move |data| {
            // (what goes here?)
            return Ok(data.len());
        }).unwrap();
        easy.perform().unwrap();
    });
    let reader = // (what goes here?)
    let reader = BufReader::new(GzDecoder::new(reader));
    for line in reader.lines() {
        let line = line?;
        println!("{line}");
    }
    handle.join().unwrap();
    return Ok(());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a type that serves as an in-memory `Read` implementation which you can write into:

```rust
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::io::{self, Read};
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};
use std::sync::{Arc, Condvar, Mutex};

#[derive(Clone, Default)]
pub struct InMemoryStream {
    inner: Arc<InMemoryStreamInner>,
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct InMemoryStreamInner {
    data: Mutex<VecDeque<u8>>,
    condvar: Condvar,
    closed: AtomicBool,
}

impl InMemoryStream {
    pub fn write(&self, data: &[u8]) {
        self.inner.data.lock().unwrap().extend(data);
        self.inner.condvar.notify_one();
    }

    pub fn close(&self, data: &[u8]) {
        self.inner.closed.store(true, Ordering::SeqCst);
        self.inner.condvar.notify_all();
    }
}

impl Read for InMemoryStream {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        let mut lock = self.inner.data.lock().unwrap();
        let read = lock.read(buf)?;
        if read > 0 {
            return Ok(read);
        }
        if self.inner.closed.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
            return Ok(0);
        }

        let mut lock = self.inner.condvar.wait(lock).unwrap();
        lock.read(buf)
    }
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```rust
fn download_and_import_file() -> MyResult<()> {
    let stream = InMemoryStream::default();
    let handle = thread::spawn({
        let stream = stream.clone();
        let mut stream2 = stream.clone();
        || {
            let mut easy = Easy::new();
            easy.url("https://example.com/file.txt.gz").unwrap();
            easy.write_function(move |data| {
                stream.write(data);
                return Ok(data.len());
            })
            .unwrap();
            easy.perform().unwrap();
            stream2.close();
        }
    });
    let reader = BufReader::new(GzDecoder::new(stream));
    for line in reader.lines() {
        let line = line?;
        println!("{line}");
    }
    handle.join().unwrap();
    return Ok(());
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks.  Two minor points: (i) InMemoryStream::close() in your answer isn't called anywhere, and InMemoryStreamInner::closed isn't modified; can I assume they're not required? and (ii) if you downvoted my question, would you mind telling me why, so I can improve future questions?

Comment: @HuwWalters (a) I was not the downvoter, and (b) `close()` not being called was a mistake, I've fixed it now; it should be called to prevent the reader from waiting forever.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll update my code with your changes.